# Transit visa for a short layover

Tags: visas, transit, japan, nrt, peruvian-citizens

My boyfriend (Peruvian citizen) is coming to visit me in the Philippines. He has a connecting flight to Narita airport that has a 2hour layover. Does he need a transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting on the same calendar day.

So no, he does **not** Need a visa